# How can I disable the Ctrl click External Link feature in FORGE Viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

During part selection in the Autodesk Forge Viewer, if you hold the Ctrl key down while selecting a part, an External Link (open hyperlink) window appears.  Is there a way to turn this feature off or disable it?

Comment: Hi Jonathan, what version of the viewer are you currently using, I cannot reproduce this workflow. the CTRL select let's me select multiples objects, no popup appears.

Comment: we are currently using version 3.2.1 of the Forge viewer

Comment: Since updating to this newer version of the viewer, I cannot reproduce the issue.  If it returns, I'll let you know.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Solution to problem explained above is to update to the latest version of the Viewer. 3.2.*